# Laravel intervention/imagecache not found

Tags: php, laravel, intervention, image-caching

I am using Laravel 5.3 with intervention image and image cache.
Today I noticed, that there's an error when I want to create a cached image (but it already worked before).

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1
> MissingDependencyException in ImageManager.php line 91:
> Please install package intervention/imagecache before running this function.

intervention/imagecache **is** installed.

I tried to reinstall it (not only intervention/imagecache, but also intervention/image), also I cleared the laravel config cache and tried "composer dump-autoload".

Unfortionately nothing helped.

Comment: Maybe autoloading is problem, laravel does not see this library?

Comment: Yes, I use composer

Comment: Almost sounds like it wasn't added to the Providers array. In config/app is there a line for the package? :-) See: https://github.com/Intervention/imagecache

Comment: It seems so...
But normally "composer dump-autoload" solves the problem, but in this case it didn't

Comment: And yes, it's included in "providers" and "aliases"

Comment: Did you try php artisan config:cache command?

Comment: Yes, I tried that

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem inside the composer.json file
There was the following code:

> "autoload-dev": {
>          "classmap": [
>              "tests/TestCase.php"
>          ]
>      },

I don't know how it got there, but after I removed it and run "composer dump-autoload" it worked again.